# WebClient.DownloadFileAsync preserving Last modified date

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download

I am using [WebClient.DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync.aspx) Method from remote server to my local machine via Windows App. I can download the file with the above method but the issue is that the "Last Modified date" which was on server for the file gets modified to current date and time when it is downloaded to my machine. I can see Last Modified date in the Response Headers for the file when it is downloaded via Fiddler. Can you help me preserving the last modified date for the file: I am using the below code:

```
 // Create a web client
        using (var client = new IfModifiedSinceWebClient())
        {
            client.IfModifiedSince = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(path);


            // Initiate an asynchronous download to a temporary file
            var downloadPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(UpdateFileIfNewerDownloadFileCompleted);
            client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, downloadPath, new UpdateFileIfNewerState(path, downloadPath, onComplete));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it when downloading synchronously.

```
File.SetLastWriteTime(filename, client.ResponseHeaders("Last-Modified"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if anybody is still interested in a working solution:

```
    public static Task DownloadFileHttp(Uri url, string localPath)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient()) {
            client.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            client.DownloadFileCompleted +=
                 (sender, e) => {
                     SetLastModified(localPath, sender as WebClient);
                 };

            return client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, localPath);
        }
    }

    private static void SetLastModified(string localPath, WebClient w)
    {
        var lastModified = w.ResponseHeaders["Last-Modified"];
        if (DateTime.TryParse(lastModified, out DateTime date))
            File.SetLastWriteTime(localPath, date);
    }
```